# Can a vote to close be reversed if a user is removed?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, user-accounts, vote-to-close

In this question which I recently revised a user was removed of SE at least from Astronomy.SE. Can their vote to close on this question also be removed?
[Can the Moon provide momentum to an object in Earth's orbit? Gravity Assisted Boost](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/19643/can-the-moon-provide-momentum-to-an-object-in-earths-orbit-gravity-assisted-bo)

Comment: There is a close vote by a moderator there. It seems that as soon as that happens, the voting ends and the close happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect not. Account deletion preserves a user's (upvoted) posts and comments, because those contributions were judged by the community to have been made in good faith. Review decisions fall into the same category, only more so: review decisions have an element of *timeliness* that questions and answers do not. (Close and delete votes expire after a few days if no consensus is reached in the review queue.) Erasing a user's review history upon deletion would presumably mean that *all* their reviews would be undone, including reviews on spammy or abusive contributions that should *not* magically be re- opened.

Comment: If a poorly received question becomes the trigger to a suspension and then later is up voted becoming well-received could  the suspension or strike be reversed?

Comment: The various restrictions on the abilities of low-quality contributors to continue posting --- the automatic post bans and manual suspensions of various lengths --- are generally based on a *pattern* of low-quality contributions, rather than on any particular post.

Comment: @Muze Somewhere I've read it on the MSE. What counts: 1) count of downvoted posts 2) count of closed posts 3) count of deleted posts. | If you have a downvoted, closed and deleted question, it counts as -3. This is why it is not a good idea to own-delete posts to get out the autoban. The automatic bans are counting this history in the last X period. I suspect, something might be in the system to ease the lifting of the autoban, probably 1 or 2 upvoted posts are already enough to come back, but it is only my estimation without any proof.